# source code problems, console errors, wont run

Tags: java, eclipse, class, console

I'm very new to java and just trying to pick up the basics.  I'm having trouble getting my code to run and the remaining errors I can't seem to figure out how to fix.

I want to create an Account object with an account ID of 00455420, a balance of $100.50, a name of “John Doe”, and an address.  Then, use the withdraw method to withdraw $4.50, use the deposit method to deposit $7.75, and use the clear method to set the balance back to 0.0.
Use the getter for your balance field to print this balance value after object creation, after the withdrawal, and after the deposit.

```
public class Account { // class name

//data fields: dataFieldName: dataFieldType
    int studentId = 00000000;//*string must be String, cant convert from int to string
    double Balance = 0.0;
    String name = ("") ;
    String address= ("");

//constructors
    // has no parameters, must have same name as class, no return type/void, invoked using "new" operator initialize objects
    Account(){// create default Account no-arg constructor 
        }
    Account(int studentId, double balance, String name, String address){ // constructor syntax 
    }

    //Methods, get/set, main, withdraw deposit clear
    public static void main (String[] args) {   // main method
        Account a1 = newAccount("00455420",100.5,"John Doe","1313 Mockingbird Lane");
        System.out.println(a1.getBalance());
        a1.withdraw(4.5);
        System.out.println(a1.getBalance());
        a1.deposit(7.75);
        System.out.println(a1.getBalance());
        a1.clearBalance();
        System.out.println(a1.getBalance());
    }
// get and set methods for balanceGet methods provide access to the value a variable holds while set methods assign values to the variables of the objects.
    public void setBalance(double num1){
        Balance = num1;
    }
    public String getBalance(){
        return static String Balance;

    //withdraw/deposit  method to - specified amt from balance
       public void withdraw(double withdrawAmount) {
            Balance -= withdrawAmount;
        }
       public void deposit(double depositAmount) {
            Balance += depositAmount;
        }
       // clear balance
       public void double clearBalance(); {
           double Balance.clear();
        }

    //methods are capable of returning values. These values can be of any primitive data type or reference type like a class. 

    }
```

CONSOLE ERRORS---------------

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method newAccount(String, double, String, String) is undefined for the type Account

    at Account.main(Account.java:19)
```

PROBLEMS--------------------

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Duplicate field Account.Balance Account.java    /Assignment/src line 33 Java Problem
Syntax error on token "void", volatile expected Account.java    /Assignment/src line 43 Java Problem
This method requires a body instead of a semicolon  Account.java    /Assignment/src line 43 Java Problem
Syntax error on token ".", ; expected   Account.java    /Assignment/src line 44 Java Problem
The method newAccount(String, double, String, String) is undefined for the type Account Account.java    /Assignment/src line 19 Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements    Account.java    /Assignment/src line 33 Java Problem
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody Account.java    /Assignment/src line 33 Java Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    Assignment 1        Unknown Java Problem
This method must return a result of type String Account.java    /Assignment/src line 33 Java Problem
Duplicate field Account.Balance Account.java    /Assignment/src line 6  Java Problem
Unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.8]' in project 'TEST'    TEST        Build path  Build Path Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    TEST        Unknown Java Problem
Build path specifies execution environment CDC-1.1/Foundation-1.1. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.     Assignment      Build path  JRE System Library Problem
Unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.8]' in project 'Assignment 1'    Assignment 1        Build path  Build Path Problem
Build path specifies execution environment CDC-1.1/Foundation-1.1. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.     Exercise4a      Build path  JRE System Library Problem
The method clear() is undefined for the type Account    Account.java    /Assignment/src line 44 Java Problem
```

Comment: Is `Balance` meant to be a double? If so, change the line to be `Balance = 0.0;` should fix it.

Comment: What do you think `The method newAccount(String, double, String, String) is undefined for the type Account` means?

Answer (score 1):

there should be a space between `new` and `Account`

```
 Account a1 = new Account("00455420",100.5,"John Doe","1313 Mockingbird Lane");
```

in addition to that your have defined a constructor with `int` for `studentId` but parsed a String

so change the `studentId` to be a String and change the constructor to accept string rather than an `int`

And there's whole lot of other things needs be changed. if you want something to that compiles here's the my version of it. I don't know whether this is exactly you want but you can find the errors you have made

```
public class Account { // class name

//data fields: dataFieldName: dataFieldType
    String studentId = "00000000";//*string must be String, cant convert from int to string
    double Balance = 0.0;
    String name = ("") ;
    String address= ("");

//constructors
    // has no parameters, must have same name as class, no return type/void, invoked using "new" operator initialize objects
    Account(){// create default Account no-arg constructor 
        }
    Account(String studentId, double balance, String name, String address){ // constructor syntax 
    }

    //Methods, get/set, main, withdraw deposit clear
    public static void main (String[] args) {   // main method
        Account a1 = new Account("00455420",100.5,"John Doe","1313 Mockingbird Lane");
        System.out.println(a1.getBalance());
        a1.withdraw(4.5);
        System.out.println(a1.getBalance());
        a1.deposit(7.75);
        System.out.println(a1.getBalance());
        a1.clearBalance();
        System.out.println(a1.getBalance());
    }
// get and set methods for balanceGet methods provide access to the value a variable holds while set methods assign values to the variables of the objects.
    public void setBalance(double num1){
        Balance = num1;
    }
    public double getBalance(){
        return Balance;
    }
    //withdraw/deposit  method to - specified amt from balance
       public void withdraw(double withdrawAmount) {
            Balance -= withdrawAmount;
        }
       public void deposit(double depositAmount) {
            Balance += depositAmount;
        }
       // clear balance
       public void clearBalance() {
           Balance = 0.0;
        }
}
```